# Global counter as argument

Tags: counters

I am in a need of a global counter which I can be used as argument to a method. When it is used as an argument, I just want the current value of it... so what the method receives is a number, not the counter. Hope I am clear.

Do you have any advice on how to create such a setup?

Here is a example showing the problem I have where the counter is increased unintented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{myCounter}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GetUinuqieID}{}{%
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter
}

\makeatletter%
% Arguments:
%  1) The text
%  2) The label
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
   #1\phantomsection\label{#2}% Print and store label
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textlabel{\GetUinuqieID}{DDD} % prints 1, expected
\ref{DDD} % prints 2, expected 1
\textlabel{\GetUinuqieID}{FFF}
\ref{FFF} 
\textlabel{\GetUinuqieID}{GGG}
\ref{GGG} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question is not clear at all (an example document would, as always, make it clearer), but if you have a latex counter such as `section` (all latex counters are global) then the numeric value is `\value{section}`

Comment: Note however that you can't change the counter's value inside of your macro if you hand in the value of that counter and not the name.

Comment: Okay, I will try aiain. Just a sec.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added an example

Comment: If you want to be able to refer to the value of `myCounter` with `\label` and `\ref` you should probably be using `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`. In that case you can get rid of `\phantomsection`.

Comment: `\xdef\currentvalue{\arabic{...}}` will store the current value as text in a global macro.  `\setcounter{mycounter}{\value{...}}` will store the current value in mycounter (also global) without converting to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to be able to refer back to counters is by using `\refstepcounter` instead of `\counter`, then the next `\label` will automatically pick up the right value.

Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{myCounter}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GetUinuqieID}{}{%
  \refstepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter
}

\makeatletter%
% Arguments:
%  1) The text
%  2) The label
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
  #1\label{#2}% Print and store label
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textlabel{\GetUinuqieID}{DDD} % prints 1, expected
\ref{DDD} % prints 2, expected 1
\textlabel{\GetUinuqieID}{FFF}
\ref{FFF} 
\textlabel{\GetUinuqieID}{GGG}
\ref{GGG} 
\end{document}
```

should work and gives

> 1 1 2 2 3 3

as expected.

Depending on the intended use case, this could probably be simplified a bit.

Indeed the problem with the code in the question was (amongst others) that `\GetUinuqieID` is a robust command, which means that it did not expand to a number in `\edef\@currentlabel`. Instead the label was made out to `\GetUinuqieID` and that command was only expanded when the label was printed in `\ref`, which meant that at that point the counter would be incremented again, leading to

> 1 2 3 4 5 6